# Money in keywords?

Tags: seo, keywords, money

Is it a good idea to put money in keywords e.g. 'Name of Item from £30'

Will google not register the pound sign therefore registering 'Name of item from 30' which could be anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a quick test and $30 returns different results to 30, but £30 does not (even in the UK). So it seems Google does not understand the pound symbol but does understand the dollar.

You can add hidden mark-up to content that adds semantic meaning to it, such as mark-up that states "this is a price and it's in GBP". schema.org is a good place to start learning about that sort of stuff.

Here's a small snippet of html that shows the sort of thing you would do:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
Name of Item from <span itemprop="price">30</span>
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
</div>
```

This would normally be placed in context with more mark-up that indicated what the price related to.

There are no guarantees that Google will use this information, however, Google is pushing it's use and I believe will be enhancing it's support over time.

One known use is that you can mark-up a product and it's price. This information may be used to give you an enhanced listing in search results. Called a rich snippet.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic

Comment: Great thanks for that... very useful... haven't heard of schema before but it does sound very interesting... will give it a look into now!